# Binding to a Binary Tree in Knockoutjs

Tags: binary-tree, knockout.js, observable

I'm looking for some advice on binding knockoutjs to a binary tree with dependentObservables.

I'm working on a web project that involves a binary tree in javascript.  The binary tree implementation has been completed, and I'm running into a problem using it with Knockoutjs.

The binary tree doesn't really have any properties, only a few methods (addNode, inorderTraversal, getLength, getDepth, toJSON, etc), so I have no clue how to set it up as observable.  I'd really just love to have a few dependentObservables that get some information from the binary tree.

As a simple example, I'd like to at least set up a dependentObservable for the length of the tree.  It just never seems to get fired...

```
viewModel.TreeLength = ko.dependentObservable(function(){
return this.bTree().getLength();}, viewModel);
```

The following adds the node to the tree, but the TreeLength never fires.

```
viewModel.bTree().addNode(new Node('some data'));
```

Comment: What happens when you add a node to bTree?  Your dependentObservable will depend on `bTree`, but unless it is updated it will not trigger a re-evaluation.  Your API might want to call `bTree.valueHasMutated()` if the actual observable is not changing and just properties on the bTree object.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - Internally, the node is just added to the tree in proper location (and the length and depth functions would return new values).  It could be triggered by multiple events.  Nothing happens in the interface or in knockout.  Can you tell me more about how I would use bTree.valueHasMutated?

Comment: Every observable has a `valueHasMutated` method available.  It tells the observable to signal its subscribers that something has changed.  Typically you don't have to call this yourself, because it happens when you update observables or call array methods on an observableArray.  However, in your case where you are not actually updating the observable and just a sub-property, you might want to consider having your APIs call valueHasMutated after making updates to the tree.

Comment: Ah!  I just found that the observable object has ValueHasMutated.  I was trying to figure out how to add it to the binaryTree directly and use it with knockout...  Previously, I've just been resetting the observed object, so this won't change the number of lines of code, but maybe I can pass a callback function to the tree and have it called that way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael, if you managed to get a solution can you answer your question to help people in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RP Niemeyer pointed me to the solution with valueHasMutated. The first round was just adding a call to viewModel.bTree.valueHasMutated() every time we worked with the tree.

Once this was proven to work, the code was refactored to pass a callback method to the tree, so that any time the tree changed, the callback would be invoked. We ran into some problems with closures, but finally got to the following:

```
function getCallBack(o) 
{
  var obj = o;
  var func = function() 
  {
    obj.bTree.valueHasMutated();
  }

  return func;
}

this.bTreeChanged = getCallBack(this);
model.bTree = new BinaryTree(model.treeData, this.bTreeChanged);
```